# Copy a file from server to local hard disk

Tags: macos, unix, ssh, scp

I'm trying to copy a database dump sql file from my server to my hdd using mac OSX Terminal (open ssh client). I know the command should be something like:

```
scp [[user]@host]:mydump.sql mydump_local.sql
```

But I found out that it did `copy` that file on the same server instead of my hdd (i.e. using `ls *`, I found both files mydump.sql and mydump_local.sql)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: were you ssh'd into the server when you ran the copy? You have the syntax correct.

Comment: yes, i did login via ssh before execute scp command

Comment: That the problem. If you ssh'd to the remote server, you are copying the file onto the remote host.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

first, don't ssh into the remote server. then, I find this to be a very good resource for scp syntax: [Example syntax for Secure Copy (scp)](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php)

the one your looking for is this: to copy the file "foobar.txt" from a remote host to the local host

```
$ scp your_username@remotehost.edu:foobar.txt /some/local/directory
```

if you're still having issues, please post the exact command you're using

Comment: `first, don't ssh into the remote server.` that was THE problem! thanks.... now, thinking about it, it's obvious: i was asking to copy from the server to the 'root', that beeing loggedin on server was the server's root instead of my hdd's root :)

Comment: What if I get a `read-only file system` error, and the copy didn't work???

Answer (score 0):

try to use ./mydump_local as the destination when you want it to be placed in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you firt make a ssh connect to the remote host, you'll get a remote shell. If you are coping your file in that remote-shell, you make a scp onto the remote server.

Don't make a ssh to the remote host, just use scp.